# Display Message box if value is greater than 0

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that allows users to go to various other forms so it's a "Main form". I'd like for a message box to appear if there are any values on a certain report greater than 0. I know how to generate message box's. How do I go about displaying that message box on the form if any value in the report is greater than 0 from a specific field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report is going to be driven by a query I'm assuming, since most are.  So, what I'd do is open the query and check for values greater than 0.

Let's assume your report is driven by a query called MyQuery.  I'd add this to the form in the appropriate place (maybe on the button click event for the report?):

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordSet("Select * from MyQuery where SomeField > 0")

If rec.EOF Then
  ...Do whatever, or ignore because no values are greater than 0
Else
  MsgBox "At least one value in the field SomeField is greater than 0"
EndIf
```

This is how you can handle it strictly using VBA.